# javascript mxins using `Object.assign`, evaluation earlier than expected

Tags: javascript, mixins, getter

I have the fowlling mixins, with a setter and a getter:

```
const dataentity_compnts_mixins = {
    set within_context(val_obj) {
        switch (val_obj["dataentity_morphsize"]) {
            case 'compact':
                this.shadow_wrapper.setAttribute(
                    "within-context", "compact_dataentity");
                break;

            case 'expanded':
                this.shadow_wrapper.setAttribute(
                    "within-context", "expanded_dataentity");
                break;
        }
    },

    get within_context() {
        const host_dataentity = this.parent_dataentity ||
            this.closest('independent-data-entity') ||
            this.closest('dependent-data-entity');
        this.parent_dataentity = host_dataentity;

        const context_dict = {
            "dataentity_morphsize": host_dataentity.getAttribute("morph-size"),
            "dataentity_role": host_dataentity.getAttribute("entity-role")
        };
        return context_dict;
    }
};
```

then I use `Object.assign` to merge this into my custom element's prototype:

```
Object.assign(IndividualviewEditor.prototype, dataentity_compnts_mixins); [1]
```

I was expecting that the getter and the setter won't be evaluated until being called with `this` refering to the host object, which in my case is the `IndividualviewEditor` custom element. However, when run this code on my webpage, I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.closest is not a function ...
```

I checked the callstack, which suggests that the getter is being called by the line [1].

I've done many searches on google and totally lost. This getter is evaluated when being merged into my prototype?? this is much earlier than I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.assign` copies all own enumerable properties to the left, meaning that getters are retrieved, and their returned value is copied, but the getter functionality itself is lost.

```js
const mixin = {
  get random() {
    console.log('I am mixin', this === mixin);
    return Math.random();
  }
};

const reference = {};

Object.assign(reference, mixin);

console.log("-------");
```

With this code you'll read in console `I am mixin true`, because the `random` accessor is retrieved during the copy.

The `reference.random` will indeed always point at the same number generated *only* during the `Object.assign` operation.

To shallow copy properties you need to pass along descriptors, and the primitives to do so are `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`.

Let's try again:

```js
const mixin = {
  get random() {
    console.log('I am mixin', this === mixin);
    return Math.random();
  }
};

const reference = {};

Object.defineProperties(
  reference,
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(mixin)
);

console.log("-------");

console.log(reference.random);
reference.random = 4; //no setter - nothing happens
console.log(reference.random);
```

First thing to notice, is that you won't read anything in console, because the accessor is not, well, accessed.

However, whenever you access `reference.random` you'll  read that it's *not* the `mixin` context, and it will return a new random value each time.

Whenever you want to define mixins for classes, or plain objects, `Object.defineProperties` is the way to go.